# Is a Java applet usable online anymore?

Tags: java, jar, applet

I have a BlueJ applet that I want to run in a web browser. I've realized that the tutorial I was trying to learn from was outdated, and applets are really obsolete. What I'm trying to figure out (I'm searching but finding a lot more outdated info, hence my confusion) is what replaced applets, and if there is still a viable way to use my .jar file in a web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what replaced applets

The browser, as a runtime, has become powerful enough to make Java Applets unnecessary. Modern webapps with some amount of JavaScript on the frontend replaced Java Applets.

> and if there is still a viable way to use my .jar file in a web app.

No, there isn't. Java Applets are dead and there is no viable way to run them for the vast majority of users on the public Internet.

If you are a software developer, you should abandon applets and start learning a modern full-stack framework. There are many to choose from.

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest you taking a look at [CheerpJ](https://github.com/leaningtech/cheerpj-meta/wiki)?

It allows for both old java applet to run and for java applications in general to be executed in the browser.

There is an [extension for Chromium/Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cheerpj-applet-runner/bbmolahhldcbngedljfadjlognfaaein) that can be used for free to test the applet and our product.

Disclaimer: I work for Leaning Technologies, the company behind the CheerpJ project.